# Determine the tangent vector at any point $p=(x^1, x^2)$ on the circle $(x^1)^2 +(x^2)^2 = a^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

> Determine the tangent vector at any point $p=(x^1, x^2)$ on the circle $(x^1)^2 +(x^2)^2 = a^2$

The following problem above and its solution below was given in my class.

*Solution:* Parametric equations for the circle are $x^1 = a\cos t$ and $x^2 = a \sin t$. The tangent vector $v$ is given by $$v_p = v^1e_1 +v^2e_2$$ where $e_1 = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}$ and $e_1 = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}$. Note that $$v^1 = \frac{dx^1}{dt} = -x^2$$ and $$v^2 = \frac{dx^2}{dt} = x^1$$ and so we arrive at $$v_p = -x^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x^1} +x^1  \frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}$$

---

Now I want to make the above solution as rigorous as possible.

Now the way I understand it (using the book *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds by John Lee* as a reference), by tangent vector my lecturer means geometric tangent vector which is the element $v_p :=(p, v)  \in \mathbb{R}^n_p = \{p\} \times \mathbb{R}^n$.

Now $$T_p(\mathbb{R}^n) = \left\{ w : C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathbb{R} \ | \ w \text{ is linear and } w(f \cdot g)= f(a)\cdot w(g) + g(a)\cdot w(f)\right\}$$ so in words $T_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the set of all smooth linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ satsifying the product rule above.

Some quick facts. For any $v_p \in \mathbb{R}^n_p$, the map $D_v|_p : C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$D_v|_p (f) = \sum_{i=1}^n v^i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} (p)$$ is a derivation. So basically for any point in $\mathbb{R}^n_p$, the map which takes the directional derivative of a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the direction $v$ at $p$ is a derivation.

Furthermore $T_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as basis $$\mathcal{B} = \left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}\bigg|_p, \dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\bigg|_p\right\} := \left\{D_{e_1}\big|_p, \dots, D_{e_n}\big|_p\right\}$$ where $e_i = (0, \dots, \underbrace{1}_{i^{\text{th}} \text{ position}} , \dots, 0)$

Moreover the map $\psi : \mathbb{R}^n_p \to T_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ defined by $$\psi(v_p) = D_v|_p$$ is a vector space isomorphism. So $\mathbb{R}^n_p$ is isomorphic to $T_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as vector spaces.

---

Now with all of the above established, I'm trying to rephrase the above solution more formally.

I understand (please correct me if I'm wring) that the 'tangent vector' $v_p =(p, v)$ where $v = (v^1, v^2)$ is being *identified* with its image $\psi(v_p) = v^1\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1} + v^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}$

Now what I don't understand is how we determine $v^1$ and $v^2$ and why we need parametric equations for the circle. I don't see why $v^1$ and $v^2$ are calculated in the way they are.

Comment: I think the question is rather vague. What do you mean by "$\textit{the tangent vector}$" ? There are infinitely many vectors tangent to $(a,b)$. From what i understand, the problem probably ask about $\textit{the tangent vector of a curve on the circle at a point} (a,b)$. Have you guys learned this in class ?

Comment: @Sou You are correct, that is what the problem is asking. We have learned this in class but very informally, the class I'm attending is basically an applied maths course (so few definitions no proofs etc) and I'm trying to learn all of the material from a pure maths perspective

Comment: @Perturbative : could you use notations such as there would be no confusion between powers, indice for different functions and degrees of differentiation.

Comment: @JJacquelin I thought I was using the standard notation used in Differential Geometry. I apologize if there was such a confusion.

Comment: Look section 8.6 in Tu's Introduction to Manifolds and p.68 of Lee's smooth manifold for the explanation (both in their 2nd ed). There is an example in Tu's which pretty much similar to your problem, and the rigorous treatment in Lee's. However, you should know what "push-forward" is.

Comment: @Sou Are you referring to the subsection on *Velocity Vectors of Curves*?

Comment: Yes. But for the concrete computation look Tu's.

Comment: @Perturbative Have you solved the problem ?

Comment: Sorry @Sou, I haven't had the time to look at it since posting the question, I'll give it another go today.